# Changing the axis on ggplot geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, coordinates

I have the following dataframe

```
View(d.df)
Statements | Score | Time
-----------+-------+------
Need Ex    |4.159  | T1
Need Ex    |3.714  | T2
Interest   |2.937  | T1
Interest   |3.508  | T2
```

and my plot

```
ggplot(data=d.df, aes(x=`Time`,y=Score, fill=`Time`)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","blue"))+
  facet_wrap(~Statements)
```

Produces the right graph, but the Y axis scale does not start in zero. I want the Y axis to go from zero to 4.5.
I tried adding

```
+ scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0.0,4.5))
```

but I get an error saying:

```
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

If I try

```
+ coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,4.5))
```

the coordinates stay pretty much the same (adds a bit of padding at the bottom).
Any ideas on how to get my axis to go proportionally from 0 to 4.5 with this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your example, as the Y starts at 0 here.

My best guess is that your Score column is not numeric but a factor (this is what the error states).

Try to change this column to numeric with `d.df %>% mutate(Score = as.numeric(Score))` before plotting.